# accessing lua class functions in C++

Tags: c++, oop, lua

I have come upon a problem with binding C++ and Lua.
I have implemented a simple class system in Lua that makes me able to create an "instance" of a lua class from another lua file using

```
require 'classname'
m_newObj = classname() --"classname() creates a new instance
```

then I can access functions in m_newObj using

```
m_newObj:functionname(parameter)
```

This works perfectly fine, but I want to be able to access an instance of a lua class from C++ code.

Normally you can create access to lua functions in C++ using

```
lua_State* pL = luaL_newState();
...
lua_getglobal(pL, "functionName");
lua_call(pL,0,0);
```

But this only calls a function in a luafile, it does not call that specific function on a specific instance of the "class".

So basically what I want to do is

- get access to an instance of a lua class in C++
- call functions on specific instance

The reason why I want to do this is because I've discovered that in performance it requires a lot more to use C++ functions in lua than using lua functions in C++, So to be able to use lua to extend entities without having the lua code call a lot of C++ functions I need to get access to lua classes in C++ instead of getting access to C++ classes in lua.

Comment: "*in performance it requires a lot more to use C++ functions in lua than using lua functions in C++*" What profiling did you use to determine this? As I understand, marshaling between the two languages works the same way either way. Depending of course on how you attach your C functions to Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push your class onto the stack, `lua_getfield()` the function from it, and then copy your class back onto the top of the stack before calling the function.  Something like this:

```
int nresults = 1;                  // number of results from your Lua function

lua_getglobal(L, "classname");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "funcname");
lua_pushvalue(L, -2);              // push a copy of the class to the top of the stack
lua_call(L, 1, nresults);          // equivalent to classname.funcname(classname)
```

Comment: Sorry for disappearing, this is the answer I was looking for! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
m_newObj:functionname(parameter)
```

This is [syntactic sugar for this](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.8):

```
m_newObj.functionname(m_newObj, parameter)
```

So just do the equivalent of that from your C++ code.